# Repeated AJAX Requests with keyup, focus and Keyboard keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
$('#input').focusin(function() {
  $('#div').show();
  
  $('#input').keyup(function() {
    $('#div').show();
    //AJAX-REQUEST//
  });
});

$('#input').focusout(function() {
  $('#div').hide();
});
```

```css
#div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<div id="div">Hello World</div>
```

Hello, In my code here it shows and hide the `div` while foucsed`in` and `out`,

When i press `ctrl`, `shift`, `arrows`, `space` or `tab`, As it is now without an AJAX request, It works normally and keeps the `div` shown,

But after adding the `AJAX Request` every time i press any of the previous mentioned keys It sends the `AJAX Request` again, And refreshes the `div`.

How do i prevent that behavior when the `AJAX Request` is added?

Comment: Move the `keyup` event handler *outside* of the `focusin` handler. As it stands right now you'll be adding another AJAX request every time you click in to the input

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the problem still occurs.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is that the AJAX request is sent even when pressing CTRL etc. which you do not want, is that correct?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, Pressing any of the mentioned keys always sent the AJAX request again, I want to prevent the multiple sending.

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, note that you should move the `keyup` handler *outside* of the `focusin` handler. As it stands right now you'll be adding another AJAX request every time you click in to the input.

To address the issue, I'm assuming from your description that you only want the AJAX request to be made when a non-whitespace character is typed. If so, use the `keypress` event instead.

Also note that `focus()` and `blur()` would be more semantic here over `focusin()` and `focusout()` as there are no child elements of the `input`. Try this:

```js
$('#input').focus(function() {
  $('#div').show();
}).blur(function() {
  $('#div').hide();
}).keypress(function() {
  console.log('Making an AJAX request now...');
});
```

```css
#div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<div id="div">Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the handler for a generic keyup, but you want to run it only when the element is focused.

```
$('#input').focusin(function() {
    $(this).data('focused', true);
    $('#div').show();
});
$('#input').focusout(function() {
    $(this).data('focused', false);
});
$('#input').keyup(function() {
    if ( !$(this).data('focused') ) {
        return;
    }
    $('#div').show();
    //AJAX-REQUEST//
});
```

Comment: It fixed the problem but just needs to be modified to `hide` the div in the mentioned cases as my example. But great job.